# How to prevent the maximizing of a Form when a MessageBox is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

#### Situation

I have a Form

```
MyMainForm.Show()
```

which has a SubForm which is not shown modal

```
// Not modal, owner is MyMainForm
SubForm.Show(MyMainForm);
```

The user `minimizes` the SubForm and interacts with the MyMainForm, then a MessageBox is shown.

```
// SubForm is still opened, but minimized

// Owner is MyMainForm (same like the opened SubForm)
MessageBox.Show(MyMainForm, "Any message", ...);
```

#### Problem

The user does not click the MessageBox, but instead `maximizes` the SubForm.

**Due to the still opened MessageBox (which has the same owner!) the SubForm does not accept any input and the application seems to freeze**.

#### Question

How can I prevent the maximizing of the SubForm when there is a MessageBox shown which has the same owner?

(To bind the MessageBox to the SubForm is no option)

#### What doesn't work

I tried to recognize the maximizing by listening to Windows Messages. But when the MessageBox is shown, no Windows Message is sent!

```
public partial class SubForm : Form
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            // Works well, except when the MessageBox is shown
            // then no appropriate message is sent
            
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steve, yes they are disabled. But when the SubForm is minimzed when the MessagBox is displayed, you can maximize the SubForm. It is displayed maximized and stays disabled. In this state it coveres the MessageBox. Should I write a full working repro?

Comment: No I have repro the problem now. It seems that handling the Resize event on the subform could solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly your problem then I would try to handle the Resize event on the SubForm in this way

```
void onResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.CanFocus)
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

This approach seems to handle the reactivation of the subform when a modal message box is displayed from the owner form. Of course the exact usability depends on how big is the subform default size. It could still cover the MessageBox position. But you can still handle that modifying the subform's Location and Size properties in the same onResize event handler or experiment with the workaround explained in the comment below by [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)

Comment: Sometimes you don't think about the obvious. Sigh! (It is still strange that the form does not receive these Windows messages in this state)

Comment: Won't work if the *re-normalized subform* happens to overlap the MessageBox current position. In that case, the *right* messages can be generated setting `this.Owner.TopMost = true;` and `this.Owner.TopMost = false;` right after. It will bring the MessageBox to front.